# The type "DateToStringConverter" is not accessible

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am running Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 on x64 Windows 8.1 with all available updates applied as of 30-Dec-2014. I am running Windows 8.1 on VMWare Fusion 7 on a MacBook Pro w/ 2 processors and 4Gig allocated. Using C#, standard Blank template, and adding my own custom class. I have added the namespace to the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BindingWithValueConverters.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BindingWithValueConverters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:valueconverter="using:BindingWithValueConverters.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding WeatherViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <valueconverter:DateToStringConverter x:Key="DateToStringConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    ...
```

The "red squiggly" line remains under "valueconverter:DateToStringConverter"; If I delete the line, and start typing, "va..." Intellisense picks up "valueconverter:", so the namespace is "there". Then, the "DateToStringConverter" class shows as an option on autocomplete. Once accepted, after a brief delay, the red squiggly comes back specifying:

```
The type "DateToStringConverter" is not accessible.
```

The code builds and runs with no errors. I could continue to code, blindly. It would be optimal to fix this issue, though. Would appreciate guidance.

I have cleaned the project. I have deleted the *.suo file. The phone emulator runs as it does on a non-VM. I have run this exact project on a Windows 8.1 machine (no VM), and do not have this issue. I suspect Intellisense. Here is my converter class if helpful:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace BindingWithValueConverters.Converters
{
    class DateToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return String.Format("{0:dddd}  -  {0:d}", date);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

VMWare/Mac is the obvious difference between working and not; however, I am hopeful there is a parameter missing on my VMWare deployment or Visual Studio deployment regarding Intellisense that could resolve this. Intellisense is working everywhere else within this project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your converter class has not been given an explicit access modifier.  Make it public and it'll show up just fine.

```
public class DateToStringConverter : IValueConverter
```

Comment: Hello David... I updated, as referenced in my *.cs file, and there is no change in behavior. I was sure hoping you were correct, though... does that count? :)

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild as well?  If the old symbol is left, it could still give you an incorrect error.